# Swept aabb 3d incorrect collision resolution along negative normals

Tags: c++, collision-detection, 3d, glm, aabb

I have followed [this](https://noonat.github.io/intersect/#aabb-vs-swept-aabb) tutorial and ported it to 3d with glm.
Everything works fine when the collision normal is reported as positive ((1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)) but when it is negative the player aabb gets "stuck: on the wall demonstrated [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gl3_fnJWtuk).

Here is the code used to detect collisions:

```
  Hit AABB::intersectSegment(glm::vec3 pos,glm::vec3 delta,glm::vec3 padding)
  {
    glm::vec3 scale = glm::vec3(1.0)/delta;
    glm::vec3 sign = glm::vec3(glm::sign(scale.x),glm::sign(scale.y),glm::sign(scale.z));
    glm::vec3 nearTime = (position - sign * (hwidth + padding) - pos) * scale;
    glm::vec3 farTime = (position + sign * (hwidth + padding) - pos) * scale;
    if ((nearTime.x > farTime.y) || (nearTime.x > farTime.z) || (nearTime.y > farTime.x) || (nearTime.y > farTime.z) || (nearTime.z > farTime.x) || (nearTime.z > farTime.y))
      return Hit(false);

    float near = glm::max(glm::max(nearTime.x,nearTime.y),nearTime.z);
    float far = glm::min(glm::min(farTime.x,farTime.y),farTime.z);

    if ((near >= 1) || (far <= 0))
      return Hit(false);

    Hit hit;
    hit.time = near;//glm::clamp(near , 0.f, 1.f);
    if ((nearTime.x > nearTime.y) && (nearTime.x > nearTime.z))
    {
      hit.normal = glm::vec3(-sign.x,0,0);
    }
    else if ((nearTime.y > nearTime.x) && (nearTime.y > nearTime.z))
    {
      hit.normal = glm::vec3(0,-sign.y,0);
    }
    else if ((nearTime.z > nearTime.y) && (nearTime.z > nearTime.x))
    {
      hit.normal = glm::vec3(0,0,-sign.z);
    }


    hit.delta = hit.time * delta;

    hit.pos = pos + hit.delta;
    hit.timeVect = nearTime;


    return hit;

  }
Sweep AABB::sweepAABB(AABB box,glm::vec3 delta)
  {
    if (delta == glm::vec3(0,0,0))
    {
      Sweep s;
      s.hit.colided = false;
      s.time = 1;
      return s;
    }
    Sweep sweep;
    sweep.hit = intersectSegment(box.position, delta, box.hwidth);



     if (sweep.hit.colided)
     {
       sweep.time = glm::clamp(sweep.hit.time - EPSILON,0.f,1.f);
       sweep.pos = box.position + (delta * sweep.time);

       glm::vec3 direction = glm::normalize(delta);

       sweep.hit.pos += direction * box.hwidth;
       sweep.item = box.getSimple();
       sweep.other = getSimple();

     }
     else
     {
       sweep.pos = box.position + delta;


       sweep.time = 1;
     }

   return sweep;
  }
```

Here is my recursive method for resolving the collisions:

```
glm::vec3 project(glm::vec3 a,glm::vec3 b)
{
  return (glm::dot(a,b)/glm::dot(b,b))*b;
}
void Player::resolveColision(math_custom::Sweep& least,math_custom::CollisionMode mode,float remTime)
{
  if (mode == math_custom::SLIDE)
  {
   velocity = velocity - project(velocity,glm::abs(least.hit.normal));
  }
  if (mode == math_custom::BOUNCE)
  {
    float dot = velocity.x * least.hit.normal.x + velocity.y * least.hit.normal.y + velocity.z * least.hit.normal.z ;
    glm::vec3 u = least.hit.normal * dot;
    glm::vec3 w = velocity - u;
    velocity = w - u;

  }
  if (mode == math_custom::TOUCH)
  {
    velocity = glm::vec3(0,0,0);
  }

  if(least.hit.normal == glm::vec3(0,-1,0))
    grounded = true;

    colided = true;
    colidedAabb = aabbs->at(least.id);



}
void Player::getCollisons(std::vector<math_custom::AABB*>* aabbs)
{
  sweeps.clear();
  for (int i =0;i < aabbs->size();i++)//for every aabb in the list
  {


    math_custom::AABB broadphase = math_custom::GetSweptBroadphaseBox(*aabb,velocity);

    if (broadphase.isColiding(*aabbs->at(i)))
    {
      math_custom::Sweep s = aabbs->at(i)->sweepAABB(*aabb,velocity);
      if (s.hit.colided)
      {
        s.id = i;
        sweeps.push_back(s);
      }

    }

  }
  std::sort(sweeps.begin(),sweeps.end(),math_custom::sortByTiAndDistance);
}

void Player::move(int iter)
{

  getCollisons(&tempaabbs);
  if ((sweeps.size() != 0))
  {


    aabb->translate(sweeps[0].pos-aabb->position);

    debug::print(sweeps[0].hit.normal);
    debug::print(velocity);
    resolveColision(sweeps[0],defaultMode,1.f);

    tempaabbs.erase(tempaabbs.begin()+(sweeps[0].id));
    move(iter + 1);
  }
  else
  {
    aabb->translate(velocity);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you used the one in the tutorial, the value you used for epsilon is too small. I modified the JavaScript from the tutorial, and realized you problem happens there, too. Just lower the value of epsilon to about `0.000001f`, and you should be fine.